# Delphi 10 Seattle in iOS9 (External Exception 434C4E47432B2B00)

Tags: delphi, ios9, firemonkey, datasnap, delphi-10-seattle

I created a simple application that accesses a DataSnap server.

When I run in simulator (iOS 9) or iPad 2 (iOS 9.0.1), everything works perfectly.

When I run on the iPhone 5, an error message appears when connecting to DataSnap Server (External Exception 434C4E47432B2B00).

Any idea?

Comment: I made a bug registry in the quality of Embarcadero site and today I received the following reply. Sergey Krasilnikov added a comment - an hour ago
Hi all!
Good news, this issue has been resolved for Seattle Update 1.
From external Jira:
This is a problem with TStringHelper.InternalCompare
Next code fails with iOS9 SDK:
string.Compare('short', 'loooong', True);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sergey Krasilnikov** added a comment

Hi all!

Good news, this issue has been resolved for Seattle Update 1.

From external Jira: This is a problem with TStringHelper.InternalCompare Next code fails with iOS9 SDK: string.Compare('short', 'loooong', True);

Answer (score 0):

You must change your datasnap server(tcp/ip) to rest server(http)
And change your client plist file (Project.plist)
 Go to the bottom of the file and insert the following text above the last /dict tag:

```
            <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
            <dict>
              <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
            </dict>
```

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/davidi/2015/09/24/43917